# OpenGL - how difficult is it to learn OpenGL ES 2.0 compared to 1.1?

Tags: android, ios, opengl-es

I'm looking into learning OpenGL ES for making a little graphics engine in Android (and possibly iOS). I've only done a little in OpenGL before on Desktop.

I'm not sure whether I should learn OpenGL ES 2.0 or 1.1. When it comes to difficulty, is there a big difference between the two?

I know there's a few topics out there about the subject, pros and cons between the versions, but I am **only** looking for input on the difficulty between the two versions.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite an open question, but here goes:
The main difference between the two is that Gles 2.0 uses *shaders*, while 1.1/1.0 uses a *fixed-function pipeline*. This means you will have lots more control on what's going to show up on the screen in 2.0, but it also means you will have to learn the shading language (glsl).
This difference means that many of the gl methods that exist in 1.0/1.1 are removed from 2.0 (such as `glColorPointer`, which can be used for setting a vertex color in 1.0 would be set in the shader using a `glUniform`call in 2.0).

Another difference is the performance, 2.0 usually gives better performance compared to the earlier versions according to [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html#choosing-version).

> In general, OpenGL ES 2.0 provides faster graphics performance than
>   the ES 1.0/1.1 APIs. However, the performance difference can vary
>   depending on the Android device your OpenGL application is running on,
>   due to differences in the implementation of the OpenGL graphics
>   pipeline.

Those are the two main points that I can think of. You should read [this document](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html), for more explanations and examples from Android, but personally I'd recommend 2.0, even though it might have a slightly higher learning curve, it is worth it.

In the linked android-dev doc they do state

> Coding Convenience - The OpenGL ES 1.0/1.1 API provides a fixed
>   function pipeline and convenience functions which are not available in
>   the ES 2.0 API. Developers who are new to OpenGL may find coding for
>   OpenGL ES 1.0/1.1 faster and more convenient.

But this ease of use is not worth it in the end (according to me).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which version of OpenGL you learnt on Desktop. If you are familiar with pixel shaders or vertex shaders, then OpenGL ES 2.0 would be easy for you. Else, try 1.1.